# Using Multiple ScriptManagers

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

I have an asp.net 4.0 app where all pages use a master page.  I have several dynamic aspects going on in both the masterpage and the child of the pages. For both I'd like to be able to use the built in Microsoft ScriptManager with this kind of pattern:

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyApp.Secure
{
    public partial class myPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetString()
        {
            return "abc";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the page content itself:

```
<script>
   PageMethods.GetString(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);

    function OnSucceeded(rslt) {
        alert('cool,worked.');
    }

    function OnFailed(error) {
        alert('ooops,failed.');
    }

</script>
```

So, to use this technique I'd like to expose static [WebMethod]'s in both my masterpage and my child page.  My question is, how do I manage this with a ScriptManager?  From my understanding, I need to have a ScriptManager within a form tag (why?) so that a javascript library is added to allow me to use the PageMethods object.  Should I just create one ScriptManager in my masterpage and tuck it in a useless form tag in the masterpage?  Will that ScriptManager pickup the [WebMethod] functions in my child page?  And what about that form tag: I know I can only have  one form runat='server' tag so how would I manage a that with other forms I need within my masterpage?  Like my little form that wraps my search function at the top of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has become moot since I've abandoned using ScriptManager.  I've been able to get ExtJS to post to my [WebMethod]'s directly without having to rely on any additional Microsoft overhead.  I'm not sure why anyone that's already using a good javascript library (like ExtJs or jQuery) would take the ScriptManager route to all [WebMethod]'s.  You certainly don't need it and it just locks you into specific requires for using  tags that have nothing to do with your app.

Answer (score 0):

A ScriptManager on your masterpage will suffice (yes in the form tag). The on pages that inherit your master, place a scriptmanagerproxy control.

I think typically people use one form tag, and then for form buttons, the postback handles the action that is appropriate - like redirecting to a search page. I'm not a fan of this method, why handle a postback when you just want to redirect to a search page with a querystring. I've used javascript mostly get get around it, either on button click change the form action to whatever is appropriate, or just override the submit button type all together and have javascript build your new url and change the location bar

Comment: Thanks Prescott.  I just found a video at http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/430_Calling_Page_Methods_Using_JQuery_and_Returning_JSON_Result.aspx that I think is a much cleaner architecture.  I didn't realize that any [WebMethod] methods that you setup in your *.aspx page could be accessed via a simple URL.  I'm sure I could have figured it out using Fiddler.  So, now I plan on simply calling the [WebMethod] using my AJAX library (ExtJs) directly and getting rid of all this c-r-a-p overhead that Microsoft adds just to simply call a web method! ScriptManagers, ScriptProxies, wasted forms,ugh!

Comment: Just curious, if they are static web methods why not break them out into their own service? I assumed you needed the full page postback and viewstate stuff. Glad you found a good solution though

Comment: I already have a full-fledged REST API with OData and EF 4.0 (which I love BTW) that covers 90% of my AJAX needs.  My need for a [WebMethod] is more for services that are specific to a page.  I like the encapsulation of having the service code in the same page along with the javascript that invokes that service.   For example, on one of my pages the user press a button that submits a task to a queue via AJAX. That tiny request has nothing to do with my data model and isn't a site wide feature.  I just pound out a quick [WebMethod], add some javascript and it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net you can only have one form tag.  What you need to do is place the form tag in the master page and have no form tags in any pages that use the maaster page.  I put the ScriptManager right below the form tag in the master page as it will be seen by all the pages using the master page.  Your search function must be inside the form tags and cannot have it's own form tag, it will use the form in the master page.  using Update Panels you can isolate the seach textbox and button and do whatever you want in the code behind such as redirect to a search result page or something like that.